# PhpStorm zero config debugger freezes page when turned on

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm, xdebug

When I use the zero-config debugger of PhpStorm it sometimes just hangs/freezes the page until I turn it off, after which it usually still breaks on the breakpoint. What could this be?

Comment: Sounds like you have more than one debug session (e.g. have one in debug mode and trying to run another page/request while 1st one is still active). Either end current one first before making another request ... or increase the number of simultaneous sessions in PhpStorm settings (by defaults it's `1`; make it `2` or `3`).

Comment: Worth checking out next time it happens. Thanks! Could you create an answer? I'll accept it =)

Comment: Just tested it, and it still happens when I only have 1 phpstorm window open.

Comment: It's not about PhpStorm windows. Show your current settings (the ones that I have suggested); Maybe you can also make whole IDE screenshot when it happens? What Xdebug log has to say?

Comment: Seems to work now, not all open instances of PHPStorm had the new config running.

Comment: Thanks! Please add it as an answer =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like you have more than one debug session (e.g. have one in debug mode right now and trying to debug another page/request while 1st one is still active).

If that's so -- either end current debug session first before making another request ... or increase the number of simultaneous sessions in PhpStorm settings. By defaults it is set to `1` .. so other sessions will wait till current one ends or PHP/web server terminates such stalled session. Make it `2` or maybe even `3`.

`Settings/Preferences | Languages & Frameworks | PHP | Debug | Max. simultaneous sessions`

[image]